# Printing first line of many files in unix

Tags: bash, unix

Problem:

Printing the first line of 4 text files side by side

Suppose File 1

```
namexyz
nameabcd
So on
```

File 2:

```
producturl1
producturl2
so on
```

Similarly i have 2 more files.

Expected Output (Trying to create a CSV):

```
namexyz,producturl1,file3data,file4data
nameabcd,producturl2,file3data,file4data
```

What i tried (a newbie in unix):

```
while ((num<COUNT)) && read -u3 name && read -u4 price && read -u5 imageurl && read -u6 purl && read -u7 gdesc
do
echo "Mobiles,$1,$name,$price,,$imageurl,Amazon,$purl,Description,$gdesc" >> trial.csv
 ((num++))
done 3< names 4<amazonprice 5<imageurls 6<amazonurl 7<description
```

names, amazonprice, imageurls, amazonurls, description all are the name of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `paste` from [GNU Core Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities):

```
paste -d, file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Comment: could you please elaborate it more.

Comment: `paste` writes lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each file, separated by `,` to standard output. See: `man paste`

Comment: How to add text in paste command i.e. output should come as this : Mobiles, Amazon, File1line1, File2line2 .... Similarly for next line. So Mobile and Amazon will remain there as constant

Comment: Is File2line2 a typo? File2line1?

Comment: Append this: `| sed 's/^/Mobiles,Amazon,/'`